# Sinatra CRUD Routes for every model, route issue

Tags: ruby, sinatra, routes

Here's where I am at with my code and I think I am close.

savetomongoid is a def that pushes the params array to mongoid.

I am using activesupport for the pluralize and classify methods

```
route :get, :delete, :post, :put, '/*/*?/?*?' do |model, action, id|
  case
  when request.get?
    case action
    when "new" 
      haml '#{model}/new'
    when "show" 
      instance_variable_set('@#{model}', model.classify.find(id))
      haml '#{model}/show'
    when "edit" 
      instance_variable_set('@#{model}', model.classify.find(id))
      haml '#{model}/edit'
     else
      instance_variable_set('@#{model.pluralize}', model.classify.asc(made))
      haml '#{model}/index'
    end
  when request.post? || request.put?
    savetomongoid(model, params[model]) ? (redirect '/#{model}/') : (redirect '/#{model}/new')
  when request.delete?
    model.classify.find(id).delete ? (redirect '/#{model}/') : (puts "uhh ohh")
  end
end

get '/*' do
  haml :silence
end
```

When I try to load this with any path, I get a completely blank screen, no source, however localhost:####/ brings me to my haml :silence so some of the routes are working.

the three splats should put it's value into model, action, id. I've tries with something/something/something and I still get the no source page.

the pattern of splats and question marks is assumed to work via the readme on https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra

Can anyone give me a hand? I am almost certain this should work.

Also, can anyone suggest a method to check if the model exists to filter out generating crud for any arbitrary thing in model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case statement looks strange.

You are testing the result of request_method, which will return the string "GET", "PUT", "POST", or "DELETE" against the values of the Request's *get?, post?, or delete?* methods which return *true* or *false*.

Seems like you will always fall out the case statement with no matches.

Could should be:

> route :get, :delete, :post, :put, '/*/*?/?*?' do |model, action, id|
>       case request.request_method
>       when "GET"
>       ...

Comment: You're right, I took out the request.request_method and it evaluates the case method now. However, there is an issue with the splats on route. it captures the first splat's value, but not the second or third. So it doesn't matter what whens I have, action=""... Any ideas?